# How can the consumer write a test of the provider without any knowledge of the implementation?

Tags: api, contract

I have been reading about consumer-driven contract testing with frameworks such as Pact.  The concepts are clear when talking about testing between two services that communication via HTTP.

We have Service A (our consumer):

- Write a test that states when we POST `{'foo': 'bar'}` to Service B, Service B responds with a 201.
- Share the contract with Service B.

We also have Service B (our provider):

- Using the contract provided from Service A, replay the request against Service B.  If Service B does not respond with a 201 (possibly due to Service B implementing a breaking change), then the test fails.

Now imagine that we have an architecture where Service A sends the same message `{'foo': 'bar'}` over a message queue to be processed by Service B.  How would we verify the contract?  Service B does not respond to Service A, so we cannot test a response.  We certainly wouldn't want to test side effects of Service B, as Service A is not aware of the implementation of Service B (and therefore cannot write a consumer-driven contract).

Perhaps in this scenario, the responsibilities are inverted; Service A is the provider and Service B is the consumer. Even in this case, how can the consumer write a test of the provider without any knowledge of the implementation? There is no response to compare to.

Comment: In your test, you must simulate what would happen on the real system.   If you designed your system to function properly in real life, then it ought to respond to the same kinds of testing techniques you would use elsewhere.  Very likely that means "sharing your contract with service B" in your test.

Comment: Your terminology here is rather confusing, calling both of them "services".  Usually, it's clear which is the client and which is the server.  HTTP requests would go client-to-server, and responses from server to client.  I'm a bit puzzled as to what your questions actually are.  The first seems to be a re-statement of the scenario you've just described.

Answer (score 2):

To verify the contract, you first have to know what the contract is. From what you described in the question, the contract is "we send this message". If you have no knowledge or expectations of what B does with this, then there's nothing to verify. If service A eventually relies on some effect that the message had in B, then you can test for that effect having taken place. If not, then B is a silent sink and A cannot (and should not) test anything about it.

The only thing that you need to test is that the message you generate is actually accepted by B. For this, you either need a way for B to report errors, or else write a test where you substitute B with something that you know accepts the same messages.

Answer (score -2):

Use the client-side service discovery pattern:

[image: service discovery pattern]

> The network location of a service instance is registered with the service registry when it starts up. It is removed from the service registry when the instance terminates. The service instance’s registration is typically refreshed periodically using a heartbeat mechanism.
>
> Netflix OSS provides a great example of the client‑side discovery pattern. Netflix Eureka is a service registry. It provides a REST API for managing service‑instance registration and for querying available instances. Netflix Ribbon is an IPC client that works with Eureka to load balance requests across the available service instances. We will discuss Eureka in more depth later in this article.
>
> The client‑side discovery pattern has a variety of benefits and drawbacks. This pattern is relatively straightforward and, except for the service registry, there are no other moving parts. Also, since the client knows about the available services instances, it can make intelligent, application‑specific load‑balancing decisions such as using hashing consistently. One significant drawback of this pattern is that it couples the client with the service registry. You must implement client‑side service discovery logic for each programming language and framework used by your service clients.

Once you discover the service, you can discover the API if it uses a well-known standard such as GraphQL:

> GraphQL is introspective. This means you can query a GraphQL schema for details about itself.
>
> Query __schema to list all types defined in the schema and get details about each:

```
query LearnAboutSchema {
  __schema {
    types {
      name
      kind
    }
    queryType {
      fields {
        name
        description
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or an auto-discovery method on a URL such as Wordpress:

> To utilize the auto-discovery functionality, call WPAPI.discover() with a URL within a WordPress REST API-enabled site:
>
> var apiPromise = WPAPI.discover( 'http://my-site.com' );

or a discovery metadata such as MediaWiki:

> Since r75621, we have RSD discovery for the endpoint: look for the link rel="EditURI" in the HTML source of any page and extract the api.php URL; the actual link contains additional info.

**References**

- [Service Discovery in a Microservices Architecture - NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/blog/service-discovery-in-a-microservices-architecture/)
- [Discovery | REST API Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/discovery/)
- [Choosing A Service Discovery System – WorkMarket Engineering](https://workmarket.tech/choosing-a-service-discovery-system-1979ee55c728)
- [Discovering the GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/intro-to-graphql/#discovering-the-graphql-api)
- [Using the REST API: Discovery](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/discovery/)
- [node-wpapi Github repo: auto-discovery](https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi#auto-discovery)
- [MediaWiki API Help](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php)
- [API:Main page - MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page)
- [GitHub - eloquent/phony: Mocks, stubs, and spies for PHP.](https://github.com/eloquent/phony)

Comment: Ok, help me out here. *How* does this solve OP’s problem?